# Shutdown reboots, instead of power-off

Tags: shutdown

If I tell my computer to shutdown, it will immediately reboot instead of going power off.

Is this a BIOS thing, or Ubuntu issue?

I tried looking in my ASUS bios, but I cannot find an option for this.

Ubuntu 21.10 on i5-12600K.

I have a kernel built from source:

```
Linux deca 5.16.5bram #13 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 9 15:08:08 PST 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

NOTE: System Suspend works as expected, and powers down all fans.

### UPDATE

`$ sudo shutdown -P now` shows the same behaviour.

`$ sudo systemctl poweroff --force` does not work: it tries to shutdown, but gets stuck after switching to text console, and just sits there.

### UPDATE 2

Setting the BIOS setting *"Fast Boot"* to disabled, did not help.

Comment: try the shutdown command, see what happens

Comment: shutdown command exhibits the behaviour I described.

Comment: 12th generation Intel need even newer kernels for proper support. But yes, you should start by updating uEFI as even brand new computers need it. SSDs as well. I can also suggest trying with a 22.04 live session.

Comment: Did you try `sudo shutdown -P now`?

Comment: try this once "systemctl poweroff --force --force"

Comment: Might be good to try with less `--force`s first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **disable Wake-On-Lan** ([WoL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)) to make the shutdown command succeed.

On my ASUS BIOS, this is:

**Advanced** ->
**APM** ->
**Power-On-By-PCI-E**

Answer (score 0):

On an Asrock Intel Z97 motherboard I had the same issue after adding an ATEN CS1922 KVM. I fixed it by setting Deep Sleep to S5 in UEFI Advanced / Chipset configuration. I was able to keep Wake-On-Lan enabled and operational.