shutdown does not work - rebooting
My laptop is HP Probook 440 G9 i5.
The issue is that when I want to turn of the system it shuts down, but after ~3 seconds it starts booting again. So effectively, the shutdown works the same as the reboot feature. I was expecting it to be a hardware problem, so I even tried reinstalling windows on this machine. It's not the case, on windows it works fine.
One interesting observation: it happens only if the HDMI cable is attached and also the power cord (the charger). Disconnecting either of them makes the shutdown work fine. But I don't want to do it each time... it's very annoying.
Where do I begin troubleshooting? Please help.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook sudo[4481]:   wojtek : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/wojtek ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl poweroff --force
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook sudo[4481]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by wojtek(uid=1000)
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1]: Shutting down.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook sudo[4481]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-journald[357]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook kernel: wlp3s0: deauthenticating from d8:07:b6:7b:bc:d7 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook wireplumber[1975]: stopped by signal: Terminated
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook snapd[833]: main.go:168: Exiting on terminated signal.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-68" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-66" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-65" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::7587:6929:ad04:b46c.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-71" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook thermald[845]: Terminating ...
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-72" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Terminating
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-79" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Disconnected from D-Bus. Exiting.
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-73" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-67" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx_hd
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-70" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_hd
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-226-1" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-64" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-logind[844]: Failed to remove file descriptor "session-2-device-13-80" from the store, ignoring: Connection refused
    Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Activating special unit exit.target...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopped vte-spawn-cd641fe3-7719-4bb6-8bb2-f952aa7df81e.scope - VTE child process 4472 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 4464.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping app-gnome-at\x2dspi\x2ddbus\x2dbus-2236.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping app-gnome-google\x2dchrome-3002.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_1
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping app-gnome-org.gnome.Evolution\x2dalarm\x2dnotify-2441.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_0
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook NetworkManager[870]: <info>  [1732292000.2941] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping app-gnome-org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.DiskUtilityNotify-2493.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping app-gnome-update\x2dnotifier-3554.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook power-profiles-daemon[823]: GLib-GIO       Error releasing name org.freedesktop.UPower.PowerProfiles: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopped target bluetooth.target - Bluetooth.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopped target default.target - Main User Target.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopped target gnome-session-wayland@ubuntu.target - GNOME Wayland Session (session: ubuntu).
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping dconf.service - User preferences database...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping evolution-addressbook-factory.service - Evolution address book service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook bluetoothd[812]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping evolution-calendar-factory.service - Evolution calendar service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.102.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping evolution-source-registry.service - Evolution source registry...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv6 with address ::1.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping filter-chain.service - PipeWire filter chain daemon...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lo.IPv4 with address 127.0.0.1.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook ModemManager[926]: <msg> caught signal, shutting down...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook rsyslogd[941]: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2312.0" x-pid="941" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-daemon.service - Virtual filesystem service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook avahi-daemon[811]: avahi-daemon 0.8 exiting.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-metadata.service - Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-metadata.service - Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service - Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping pipewire-pulse.service - PipeWire PulseAudio...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service - Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd->
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping tracker-miner-fs-3.service - Tracker file system data miner...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service - Portal service (GNOME implementation)...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation)...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping xdg-document-portal.service - flatpak document portal service...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopping xdg-permission-store.service - sandboxed app permission store...
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd[1954]: Stopped gnome-keyring-daemon.service - GNOME Keyring daemon.
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook wireplumber[1975]: disconnected from pipewire
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-a11y-settin[2391]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-housekeepin[2397]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-screensaver[2421]: Error releasing name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gnome-remote-de[816]: Error releasing name org.gnome.RemoteDesktop: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-sound[2437]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-color[2392]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-sharing[2426]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-rfkill[2418]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gsd-smartcard[2433]: Error releasing name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard: The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook gnome-shell[2233]: Could not release device '/dev/input/event4' (13,68): The connection is closed
Nov 22 17:13:20 wojtek-probook systemd-journald[357]: Journal stopped


You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; and if you were using a LTS release which kernel stack you used (default being set by install media). First troubleshooting step would be working what you're running; then try various commands (setting runlevel, shutdown, poweroff, sysrq direct command etc) and seeing if you get same result for each.  Your description indicates the HDMI connection is sending a signal that maybe preventing shutdown which is something to explore when you've worked out what you're actually running

Sorry for not being specific on my system and hardware.
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
kernel version 6.8.0-49-generic
runlevel is 5
I'm not an expert and really would appreciate further tips to solve this. Thanks in advance :)

Welcome to ASK. Take a look at the answers to this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398330/shutdown-reboots-instead-of-power-off The following link describes the power off process and might give you somewhere to start debugging your problem. https://medium.com/@buzondefede/shutdown-from-power-button-explained-in-ubuntu-22-04-3fbe671b5765

Neither of those suggestions did help. Please find attached above the output of the command:
sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e

The following link refers to the solutions to this rebooting-after-shutdown event for a HP Probook 450 G0 but is caused by very particular hardware preset. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675602/hp-probook-reboots-immediately-after-shutdown You should also check the BIOS to see if there is any adjustable hardware that is capable of waking the PC such as ethernet or even that bluetooth device you have that seems to be having trouble shutting down. Good luck.

Out of curiosity, What happens if you run halt -p
